# Code assist (ctrl+space) doesn't work on Eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse

Code assist (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>) doesn't work on Eclipse Kepler. This happened to me this morning.

Comment: Surely the Eclipse mailing list/bug tracking system would be a better place for an Eclipse bug report...?

Comment: Eclipse does not qualify as " tools used primarily for programming"? Mind Blown. (abou the off-topic shutdown).

Comment: It is mind boggling what you people will close as off topic... just reading the blurb it gives you about off topic questions should tell you it's NOT OFF TOPIC. good job people. +1 for good question and good answer to a PERTINENT PROGRAMMING RELATED QUESTION.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986750/ctrl-space-not-working-for-content-assist-on-eclipse

Answer (score 143):

This happend to me too.

For some reason Kepler changes the settings for Content Assist on Juno workspaces. Checking the `Java Proposals` checkbox in `Preferences -> Java\Editor\Content Assist\Advanced` should resolve this problem.

Comment: awesome - thanks for the tip. i always having this issue with Eclipse Kepler version.

Answer (score 16):

My workaround to this problem: it seems that some component of Eclipse Kepler doesn't like workspace from older Eclipse version. Starting Eclipse with new workspace and reimporting projects solved the problem.