# Auto-complete not working for paintComponent(Graphics g) in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, configuration, awt

Why "Control + Space " auto-complete help doesn't work for paintComponent() method and it needs to be typed in completely?

Comment: Can you tell as the os version and eclipse version!

Comment: Or you can see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358312/code-assist-ctrlspace-doesnt-work-on-eclipse-kepler).

Comment: eclipse - Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2), OS- windows 7. Auto complete works for other features, not for this one only

Answer (score 0):

Its because there might be an ambiguity between the paintcomponent of AWT/Swing and the parameters that it needs consists of 1D and 2D graphics. You might have imported both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Probably error. In case of error sometimes eclipse didn't show error, but in result members aren't listed for auto complete.

Comment: only for that particular method its not giving that feature, though its working fine for others. Does it shows for you ?